# overflow-x not working on chrome mobile

Tags: html, css, overflow, parallax

I'm trying to make a css parallax site. On the desktop everything works fine but on mobile devices I get a horizontal scrollbar caused by transform3d scale (also with overflow-x:hidden on the parallax class). If I change to overflow:hidden it works but then I can't scroll the content anymore.

```
$parallax-perspective : 1 !default;

.parallax{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  @include perspective($parallax-perspective*1px);
  @include transform-style(preserve-3d);
}

.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  @include transform-style(preserve-3d);
}

@mixin parallax__layer(
$distance    : 0,
$perspective : $parallax-perspective
) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  @include transform3d(
      translate3d(0,0,$distance * $perspective * 1px)
      scale(abs($distance - 1), abs($distance - 1)));
  z-index: $distance * 1000;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  @include parallax__layer(0);
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  @include parallax__layer(-1);
}


<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer--base"></div>
    <div class="parallax__layer--back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `body { overflow: hidden; }` This is counter intuitive, but it solved my problem. For some reason the parallaxed layers aren't considered overflow on the y but are on the x. Maybe some one could shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

It is working with a wrapper class

```
.parallax__inner{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this more?